# I'm trying to print all the files in a directory with there file size. I have it outputting all my info but in the wrong order

Tags: c, recursion, directory

this is my current code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <time.h>




int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
        struct stat file_stat;
        DIR *dirp;
        struct dirent* dent;
        long size = 0;
        if(argc > 1){
                dirp = opendir(argv[1]);
                printf("%s",argv[1]);
        }
        if(argc == 1){
                argv[1] = ".";
                dirp = opendir(argv[1]);
                printf("dir .\n");
                do{
                        dent = readdir(dirp);
                        if(dent){
                                char* fileName = dent->d_name;
                                if(fileName[0] == '.'){
                                        continue;
                                }
                                printf("\t%s\n",dent->d_name);
                                if(!lstat(dent->d_name, &file_stat)){
                                        printf("\t%d:",(int) file_stat.st_size);
                                        size += (int)
                                        file_stat.st_size;
                                }
                        }
                }while(dent);
                printf("\n\nTotal file space used:%ld\n",size);
                closedir(dirp);
        }
}
```

As of right now I only have it printing the files of the current directory.
My output is printing all my correct file sizes and file names. But it's printing it out of order. Each line should have the "fileSize: fileName". Currently it prints the first filename and the prints the size on the next line. Making each Filename have the size of the file before it. My output is below

```
dir .
        p7.c.save
        564:    p7.c.save.3
        466:    p7
        8632:   Makefile
        44:     n
        0:      p7.c
        779:    p7.c.save.4
        384:    p7.c.save.2
        360:    p7.c.save.1
        559:
```

This is what my output should roughly look like. I am newer to C and have been struggling with fixing the format of my output. If anyone could help me out or point me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it!!!

```
$ ./p7
dir .
   17371:p8
     170:Makefile
    1715:p8.c
   11416:p8.o

Total file space used:30672
```

Comment: Edit you question and include everything related. Please don't post screenshots of code...

Comment: Will do! I will update my post now :D

Comment: I don't see recursion btw. You are using a `do ... while` loop.

Comment: `argv[1] = " . "` why would you do that ?

Comment: You're printing a newline and a tab between the file name and size... Of course they're going to be on different lines.